# Need help understanding FF indirect call instruction x86

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I'm trying to recode a simple ftrace but I'm having trouble understanding FF indirect calls like this one :

```
ff 15 76 0b 20 00       callq  *0x200b76(%rip)        # 600ff0 <__libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5>
```

Does it work like the E8 instruction with an offset ? If not, how to find the address the call point to ? And the address of return of that call ?

Comment: Isn't your debugger/disassembler giving you the target address in the comment out to the side? It's calling `__libc_start_main`. It'll return like any other function call.

Comment: @CodyGray That is not correct. It is calling whatever is stored at that address.

Answer (score 6):

The instruction `callq  *0x200b76(%rip)` does the following things:

1. Load one 64 bit word from `rip + 0x200b76` where `rip` is the *instruction pointer*. According to the comment, this should be the address `0x600ff0` but it can be different if your code is relocated.
2. Push the address of the next instruction on the stack as a return address.
3. Jump to the value of the datum we read in step one.

The difference to the normal `call` (i.e. opcode `e8`) instruction is that this is an *indirect function call* where the address we call is loaded from memory instead of being specified right there. This is indicated by the asterisk (`*`). `call foo` is to `call *foo` like `mov $foo,%eax` is to `mov foo,%eax`.

Answer (score 1):

Jumps can be characterized by several properties:

- Direct or indirect (i.e. whether the address is given in the instruction or retrieved from a memory pointer).
- Relative (address is given as an increment, *relative* to where the `CALL` opcode is) or absolute (jump to the actual, provided address). Indirect jumps are always absolute.
- Near (in the same segment) or far (in a different segment). Far jumps are always absolute.

Now, `E8` is direct, near, and relative. In contrast, `FF` is indirect, near, and absolute. There is a variant of `FF` that's far rather than near, which is used mainly for call gates AFAIK. See [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html) for a succinct table of `CALL`s.

See also this: [How can I tell if jump is absolute or relative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544052/how-can-i-tell-if-jump-is-absolute-or-relative).

So to your questions:

> how to find the address the call point to

The `15` indicates that the pointer is relative to `RIP` (if it were relative e.g. to `RAX` then you'd have `ff 90`). The offset relative to `RIP` is in the four bytes immediately following the `15` - in your example, these are `0x00200b76`. See [Why call instruction opcode is represented as FF15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837363/why-call-instruction-opcode-is-represented-as-ff15) for additional explanation on decoding.

> the address of return of that call

The return address is always the instruction immediately following the `CALL` instruction. So if the `CALL` is at address `0x100000` then the return address will be `0x100006`.

Comment: Note that the whole opcode is `ff /2` as one digit of the modr/m byte is also part of the opcde. That other variant of `ff` you mean is an indirect far call, opcode `ff /3`. Note that many other instructions have opcode `ff` (such as, `inc r/m32` and `dec r/m32`) with different extended opcodes.

Comment: @fuz That's a fair point. My mentioning of the `ff /3` variant was for completeness, not because this is the example given by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Indirect branches (indirect jumps and indirect calls) are the main challenges for binary analysis tools. you need to check several tools to understand how these tools deal with indirect branches. Most popular binary analysis tools are:

- IDA Pro
- Radare2
- Dyninst
- Ghidra
- BAP

Those technique use different approaches to resolve indirect branches (compiler patterns, recursive disassembly, and propagation).
However, in my opinion, there is no tool that is able to resolve all types of indirect branches.

Important note:
Indirect branches are:

1. indirect jumps,
2. indirect call functions,
3. tail functions, and
4. non-returning function